# stop command "watch" after it showing data

Tags: bash

I am trying to use output from a built in command in a firewall vendor. The script shows important information using watch.
However I need to make watch stop after it has outputed the data.

I have tried to cat the file, removing watch from the file but it doesn't work very well.
Perhaps I can send it a Ctrl + C right away using echo? I have done something similar on another interactive script, where I did: echo -e "2\nQ" | command to make it select number 2, then press Q to make it quit.

Any other ideas to make watch die after it has shown the data?

Comment: Maybe you can use the key `-g` that stops `watch` command when the output changes

Comment: Not sure I understand. You mean that if i do watch "date" and press -g it should stop on the next time it changes? I cannot get it to work interactively.

Comment: `watch -g your_command`. See `man watch`.

Comment: Perhaps the device has an older verison of watch,
[user@device]# watch -g "date"
watch: invalid option -- g
Usage: watch [-dhntv] [--differences[=cumulative]] [--help] [--interval=<n>] [--no-title] [--version] <command>